# best advertising platform for apps outside microsoft's ad platform

Tags: windows-phone-7, ads

I am a developer that doesn't have access to the microsoft ad platform for windows phone(not in the contries allowed to participate). What is the best ad platform(ported or native to WP) to work with in these conditions?

**UPDATE** i found **[AdMob](http://admobwp7.codeplex.com/)** wrapper for WP on codeplex. Is it a good solution?

Comment: admob has an official WP wrapper. Check it out on their website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say http://www.adduplex.com/ , since the authors are well known in the developer community.

Comment: from what i know, adduplex is only for advertising your app, not generating revenue. This system doen't work if you have only a free-app(no commercial app).

Answer (score 4):

try http://www.inner-active.com . It works even if our app is not published on marketplace.

Comment: looks interesting. i'll give it a look!

Answer (score 1):

I found following article regarding this topic it discussed multiple ads solutions and even some ads switching providers and controls

http://briankassay.com/blog/?p=169